# Why is there no flag link in the LQP queue?

Tags: feature-request, review, low-quality-posts

[This review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5521996), for example, should certainly be flagged for spam. But to do so, I have to click the question title below and find the answer. Why can't there be a <kbd>Flag</kbd> button next to the <kbd>Recommend Deletion</kbd> button?

Comment: Update: my spam flag was declined because the answer was removed. I'm unable to view removed answers, but it was along the lines of `>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` (albeit longer).

Comment: Well, technically it's not spam - it doesn't contain any thing remotely like an advertisement.

Comment: Yeah, it needed a low quality flag, not spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason there is no flag link in the Low Quality Review Queue is because one major way that posts end up in that queue is from users flagging answers. So they have already been flagged in a lot of cases, as such, it is now the reviewers job to see if the post should be deleted or not.

Comment: but it's not the only way. Why go to the trouble of hiding the flag link for all entries, just because some of the entries in there have been flagged?

Comment: @KateGregory I'm sure the stats are out there somewhere, I'd think it's not just some, but probably about half that are there b.c user flagged, and other half b.c system flagged to go there. ----- There's a reason that < 3k'ers can't review in the close queue. They don't have close votes. Makes no point in letting them in the queue so they can flag to close just so the question remains in the close queue. Low quality queue is for deleting/editing/ or looks OK. Not flagging in my opinion.

Comment: Also, most the time there's an actual spam post in the low quality queue, it's an audit. So just recommend deletion on them. If it turns out not to be an audit, you can click the back button and go to the answer directly to flag as spam.